# Grails select will not return correct data

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

This a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959777/grails-chained-drop-down) question.

I have an `Address` class which contains basic street address information.  I also have a `User` class which has the attributes `physicalAddress`, `mailingAddress`, `cargoDestinations`, and `cargoSources`.  The `User` class looks something like this:

```
class User {

    String username
    String password
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String businessName
    String phoneNumber
    Address physicalAddress
    Address mailingAddress
    static hasMany = [accounts:Account, cargoSources:Address, cargoDestinations:Address, cargoes:Cargo, loadsLogged:Load, loadsDelivered:Load]
    Set accounts, cargoSources, cargoDestinations, cargoes
    static mappedBy = [loadsLogged:"loggedBy", loadsDelivered:"deliveredBy"]

//some other stuff after this
```

And the `Address` class looks something like this:

```
    class Address {

        static belongsTo = [user:User]

        String streetAddress
        String city
        String state
        String zip

        BigDecimal taxRate

//some other stuff after this
```

I followed the tutorial [here](http://moongrails.blogspot.com/2008/12/grails-ajax-chained-select.html) for the most part.  In step 5 my template looks like this:

```
<g:select
  from="${account.user.cargoDestinations}"
  name="cargoDestinations" value="">
</g:select>
```

The problem is that instead of returning only `cargoDestinations`, the template returns ALL addresses associated with that user.  If I change `from="${account.user.cargoDestinations}"` to `from="${account.user.physicalAddress}"` or `from="${account.user.mailingAddress}"` I get the expected result, so I know my problem has something to do with how the `cargoDestinations` variable is mapped.  How can I go about fixing this without changing my class files too much?

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) are the `User` and `Address` relationships bidirectional? 2) if so, do you have a [`mappedBy`](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html) on your `User` domain? ... not sure if not having that would cause this, but it's something to look at.

Comment: @Rob I updated my question, providing some more details on my classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding several boolean fields to my address class, which made the design simpler and much easier to work with.  This way I only need one class instead of several nearly identical classes.  The boolean fields in the `Address` class now indicate if an address is a physical address, mailing address, cargo source, etc., or all of the above.  As @ataylor pointed out, this system makes it so an address object can only be associated with one user from my `User` class, but it does not seem like that will ever be an issue.  The worst case is that a multiple users would have the same address in real life, and my program would require the creation of a separate address object for each of those users, even though the addresses in question would be identical.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have your addresses mapped, they all link back to the user on the user_id column.  You'll need to add some fields to Address to distinguish how they're related to User, similar to how you've mapped Loads.  For example:

```
class Address {
    static belongsTo = [cargoSourceFor: User, cargoDestinationFor: User]

    ...
}

class User {

    ...

    static hasMany = [cargoSources:Address, cargoDestinations:Address]
    static mappedBy = [cargoSources: "cargoSourceFor", cargoDestinations: "cargoDestinationFor"]

    ...
}
```

If you're familiar with SQL, doing a `grails schema-export` and looking at `target/ddl.sql` can be helpful when setting up mappings.

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a try, I didn't realize an object could `belongTo` more than one other object.  I did connect to the Grails database file using RazorSQL just to see how the tables were set up, but I'll try `schema-export` too.

Comment: let me ask you this, how do I address the fact that my users also have one (and only one) `physicalAddress` and one (and only one) `mailingAddress`?  Do those need to be mapped in the same fashion?

Comment: No, the difference is in how the database reprensents the relationship.  When you have one user to many addresses, as in `cargoDestinations` and `cargoSources`, the user id is stored in the address table.  When you one address to (potentially) many users, as in the `physicalAddress` or `mailingAddress`, the address id is stored in the user table.

Comment: I am still having trouble getting this working correctly, and after some deliberation I think it might be better for me to add several boolean fields to my address class, indicating if the address is a physical address, mailing address, cargo source, cargo destination, or any combination of the four. This way a User hasMany addresses and an Address belongsTo a user:User. Do you see any potential problem or drawback to this approach?

Comment: That approach sounds simpler.  It does limit each address object to be associated with only one user.